# how to access a file within a folder in view directory of hbs engine in node/express js

Tags: express, handlebars.js, render, router

Hope Youre all are doing Great,Im new in Expressjs and doing a project in it.
Actually I m getting problem to render a file that is place inside the a folder named as index.hbs in views directory,
When I try to access a found this error :
Error: Failed to lookup view "/blogger_dasboard" in views directory "C:\Users\HBK1007\Desktop\ExpressjsFyPEPakTourisum\template\views"

Im attaching folder structure images and my code as well

Here is the code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjb9I.png)
`

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const port = 8000;
const hbs =require('hbs')
const bcrypt =require("bcryptjs")

// establishing db connection 
require('./db/db_connec');

// Getting the collection of DB 
const Registration=require('./models/registrationdb')
const NewsletterSubsciber=require('./models/newsletter')
const ContactUs_Client =require("./models/contactus")



// this is for DB data conersions 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))


//public static port
const static_path = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
const tempalte_path = path.join(__dirname, '../template/views')
const bloggerdashboard_path = path.join(__dirname, '../template/views/blogger_dashboard')
const partials_path =path.join(__dirname,'../template/particles')





app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', tempalte_path)

hbs.registerPartials(partials_path)
app.use(express.static(static_path))














// BloggerDashboard Routes
app.get('/blogger_dashboard', (req, res) => {
    res.render('/blogger_dasboard')
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listning to portss ")
})
```

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I mirrored your project and You have few errors:

1. Wrong paths, too many by one dot in : `static_path`, `tempalte_path`, `bloggerdashboard_path`, `partials_path`.

---

2. Insted of `res.render("/blogger_dasboard")` like that: `res.render("blogger_dashboard")`; Without **slash** and you missed **h** letter.

---

Working example below without `static_path` `bcrypt` and `db` (for obvious reasons)..

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const port = 8000;
const hbs = require("hbs");
// const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

// establishing db connection
// require("./db/db_connec");

// Getting the collection of DB
// const Registration = require("./models/registrationdb");
// const NewsletterSubsciber = require("./models/newsletter");
// const ContactUs_Client = require("./models/contactus");

// this is for DB data conersions
// app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//public static port
// const static_path = path.join(__dirname, "./public");
const tempalte_path = path.join(__dirname, "./template/views");
const bloggerdashboard_path = path.join(
  __dirname,
  "./template/views/blogger_dashboard.hbs"
);
const partials_path = path.join(__dirname, "./template/particles");

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views", tempalte_path);

hbs.registerPartials(partials_path);
// app.use(express.static(static_path));

// BloggerDashboard Routes
app.get("/blogger_dashboard", (req, res) => {
  res.render("blogger_dashboard");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is  listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

---

My Project folder and[image] file structure: